# jQuery 1.5 scrollTop method raises exceptions

Tags: javascript, jquery, exception, google-chrome

What is this error and what can I do about this?

I made a simple div with `overflow-y: scroll` style and some content, but here's what happens when I try using jQuery.scrollTop on it (I run this from Developer Tools shell):

```
$('#s').scrollTop(100)
```

scrolls, but shows this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object 10 has no method 'apply'
jQuery.event.handle, jquery-1.5.2.js:2568
jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle.eventHandle, jquery-1.5.2.js:2207
```

I see this message every time I use scrollTop. I have Chromium 14.0.835.202 (Developer Build 103287 Linux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get no problem in my test(see below), maybe you break something by accident. Show me your whole code.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="s" style="overflow-y:scroll;height:100px;">
  some content ...
</div>
<input id="b" type="button" value="scrollTop" />
<script>
  $('#b').click(function() {
    $('#s').scrollTop(100);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Right, I must have broken something when working in the shell before that.

Answer (score 0):

Let the DOM ready before you do any action on it.

```
$(function() {
    $('#b').click(function() {
        $('#s').scrollTop(100);
    });
});
```